# How to install `kie-camel` feature in JBoss Fuse 6.2

Tags: apache-camel, jbossfuse, karaf, kie

I'm trying to deploy a drools component to a vanilla JBoss Fuse 6.2 server.

I first install the drools features url

```
JBossFuse:karaf@root> features:addurl mvn:org.drools/drools-karaf-features/6.1.0.Final/xml/features
```

before installing the drools module and kie-spring features

```
JBossFuse:karaf@root> features:install drools-module/6.1.0.Final
JBossFuse:karaf@root> features:install kie-spring/6.1.0.Final
```

However, when I attempt to install kie-camel I get the following error

```
JBossFuse:karaf@root> features:install kie-camel/6.1.0.Final
...
Found installed bundle: org.apache.servicemix.specs.jsr311-api-1.1.1 [267]
Found installed bundle: stax2-api [268]
Found installed bundle: org.apache.cxf.cxf-api [400]
Found installed bundle: org.apache.cxf.cxf-rt-management [402]
Installing bundle mvn:org.apache.cxf/cxf-rt-features-clustering/2.6.6
Error executing command: Can not resolve feature:
Unsatisfied requirement(s):
---------------------------
   bundle:(&(symbolicname=org.springframework.beans))
      Apache CXF Compatibility Bundle J
```

Any ideas how to resolve this issue? I suspect that I  might need to add another feature url but my research into that hasn't produced any results yet.

Thanks in advance

Lewis Watson

Comment: [This bug](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/ENTESB-4923) seems to point at a missing dependency in the `features.xml` of the drools bundle. I found the maven repositories for the [compatibility bundle](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.cxf/cxf-bundle-compatible) and the [JBoss version of that bundle](https://maven-repository.com/artifact/org.apache.cxf/cxf-bundle-compatible/3.1.2-jbossorg-1), but can't figure out how that transaltes into a URL to add to Fuse.

Comment: It certainly looks like a missing dependency somewhere. After speaking to RedHat I tried installing the [drools-karaf-features-6.3.0.Final-redhat-5-features.xml](https://maven.repository.redhat.com/techpreview/all/org/drools/drools-karaf-features/6.3.0.Final-redhat-5/drools-karaf-features-6.3.0.Final-redhat-5-features.xml) features url. Unfortunatley, drools-6.3.0 doesn't have a `kie-camel` component, and I haven't been able to work out what replaces it.

Answer (score 1):

I've been in contact with Red Hat support and they have provided me with a way to install version 1.4.0.redhat-63001 of `kie-camel`

```
 JBossFuse:karaf@root> config:propappend --pid org.ops4j.pax.url.mvn org.ops4j.pax.url.mvn.repositories ',https://maven.repository.redhat.com/techpreview/all/'

 JBossFuse:karaf@root> features:addurl mvn:org.drools/drools-karaf-features/6.4.0.Final-redhat-3/xml/features

 JBossFuse:karaf@root> features:addurl mvn:org.drools/drools-karaf-features/6.4.0.Final-redhat-3/xml/features

 JBossFuse:karaf@root> features:list | grep kie 
 [uninstalled] [1.4.0.redhat-630011 ] kie-camel

 JBossFuse:karaf@root> features:install kie-camel
```

Things to note about this answer:

1. It seems to rely on a tech preview maven repository.
2. I haven't yet been able to develop an OSGI bundle to test the feature.

As a workaround I was able to get something similar working with drool 5.5.0-Final by following what's on https://github.com/FuseByExample/camel-drools-example

Answer (score 0):

Can you try 6.4.0?

features:addUrl mvn:org.drools/drools-karaf-features/6.4.0.Final/xml/features

Comment: For some reason the `kie-camel` component isn't present in 6.4.0.Final. I've been unable to find any information on why it was taken out.

Comment: It seems post 6.2.0.Final as part of the integration fuse it was moved to org.jboss.integration.fuse:kie-camel